# Indexers in C# for single objects

Tags: c#

I was wondering whether it was possible to also use indexers for single objects. So,

```
class A<T> 
{ 
public T this[int index] 
{ 
//get, set using index
}
private T _t;
}
```

I was wondering whether the following was possible? (or something that looks like it)

```
class A<T> 
{ 
public T this 
{
//no indexer? essentially get { return _t; } set ...
} 
private T _t;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example how do you except to use/ call this

Answer (score 3):

You can use [implicit conversion operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx) to do this sort of thing where one type acts like another type.

The only limitation is that you can only have a getter or a setter, *not both* for a given other type.